# ngx-translate doesn't display translation in server mode

Tags: angular, angular-universal, ngx-translate

I have a problem with ngx-translation. It work in both mode - browser & server.
In browser mode everything works properly, but in server mode translation doesn't fulfill HTML source file.

I thought that a problem is my loader - I user @ngx-universal/translate-loader, but when I add `translate.get` in my constructor to test it and it works properly:

```
translate.get('works', {}).subscribe((res: string) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

This show a result in node console ("- WORKS" in "en" mode or "- DZIALA" in polish mode), so the problem is when template is rendered.

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');

    translate.get('works', {}).subscribe((res: string) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  swtitchLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="swtitchLang('pl')">PL</button>
<button (click)="swtitchLang('en')">EN</button>

<ul>
  <li><a routerLink="/" [translate]="'menu.home'"></a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="about" [translate]="'menu.about'"></a></li>
</ul>
<h4>TEXT: <span [translate]="'works'"></span></h4>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Text without translation is shown properly in my HTML source file (for example word "TEXT:" or "PL", "EN", but translation on routerLink and word after TEXT: doesn't show. Source look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Home</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link href="styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style ng-transition="ang4-seo-pre"></style>
        <meta name="author" content="Coursetro.com">
        <meta name="keywords" content="angular seo, angular 4 universal, etc">
        <meta name="description" content="This is my Angular SEO-based App, enjoy it!">
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.4.6">
            <button _ngcontent-c0="">PL</button>
            <button _ngcontent-c0="">EN</button>
            <ul _ngcontent-c0="">
                <li _ngcontent-c0="">
                    <a _ngcontent-c0="" routerLink="/" href="/"></a>
                </li>
                <li _ngcontent-c0="">
                    <a _ngcontent-c0="" routerLink="about" href="/about"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <h4 _ngcontent-c0="">TEXT: 
                <span _ngcontent-c0=""></span>
            </h4>
            <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
        </app-root>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.3df9f7567cf0da6bbb0f.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.14173651b8ae6311a4b5.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.aeb6cf8ce8b6e01353e0.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.203dfaf526cd10912720.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not define a pipe for your translation service such that you can just databind the string to it? The result would be `{{'some_string' | translate}}`

Comment: Thanks - it's work properly. Can you explain why? I found, that `<div [innerHTML]="'works' | translate"></div>` and `<div>{{ 'works' | translate }}</div>` work, but `<span [translate]="'works'"></span>` doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is that it's a timing problem. For example, a case where you are trying to do the translation before the files have loaded or the service is ready. Defining a pipe gets around it.

Comment: With DataBinding the binding updates when the value changes. So if the value goes from "" to "something" then "something" will be piped through at that time. That's why I believe it's a timing problem.

Comment: @ChrisSharp - really thanks for help. They should add this to @ngx-translate/core docs in "Use the service, the pipe or the directive" section.

Comment: You're welcome. I have put the answer below. If it solved your problem please mark it. Thanks!

Comment: I tried but I should wait 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not define a pipe for your translation service such that you can just databind the string to it? The result would be `{{'some_string' | translate}}`